# How to return one fields of updated rows?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I have the following query:

```
$updated = ResultTest::whereIn("client_id", $request->id)->update(array("mode" => 1));
```

Now it returns `$update` flag (1|0) if rows was updated.

How to get array of fields `client_id` instead boolean value?

Comment: You can't. Update returns a boolean (https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_update). You would first have to update and then get it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tap` function:

```
$results = ResultTest::whereIn("client_id", $request->id);
$updated = tap($results)->update(array("mode" => 1));

return $results->pluck('client_id');
```

https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/tap-tap-tap-1fc6fc1f93a6